# Clarification on designing a Workflow Application

Tags: asp.net, wpf

We have a workflow web application developed on ASP.Net / SQL.  Though the application is stable developed on .Net 2.0, we get performance issues.

So we are in the process of kick starting the Next Generation Application.

My clarification is whether WPF XAML based Stand Alone application will result better performance as compared to ASP.Net ?

Comment: Workflow 1.x and Workflow 2.x are totally different.  There isn't enough information here to assist.  You need to profile and describe where/why when there is a performance issue.

Comment: Workflow is going to be slow. that is how it is. There are things to speed it up, but this is a very complex issue that you need to look into deeper.

Comment: @LamonteCristo, ..this is a 3 tier application with over 10 million record..application is a traditional asp.net web application .. with bunch of javascripts on client side ..